# UITableViewCell.frame.size.width only reporting half of original size

Tags: ios, uitableview

Why is my UITableViewCell reporting half the actual value for UITableViewCell.frame.size.width. I am using a iPhone 4s for development.

```
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

NSLog says it is only 320.0

```
NSLog(@"cell width = %f", cell.frame.size.width);
```

Do anyone know why this is ? am I missing something ?

Update : I am expecting the width in pixels. is there a straight forward way to do that ?

Comment: 320 is correct (assuming your tableview takes the entire width of screen, and not more). What value were you expecting?

Comment: @n00bProgrammer I was expecting the pixel size

Comment: How to get the pixel size of the cell in pixels ?

Comment: I think you are confusing **Pixels** and **Points**. Scroll down to **Points Versus Pixels** in [THIS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/graphicsdrawingoverview/graphicsdrawingoverview.html) document for better understanding.

Comment: As for getting the right value, multiply your `width` with the screen's scale factor `[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]` to get the value you are looking for.

Comment: @n00bProgrammer Yes got it, the contentScaleFactor property will do I guess